# InfluxdB check for field changes

Tags: influxdb

We are using InfluxDB to store the health of several devices and one field is the current Status of the device. Would like to trigger an event (via logs, email, external alarms) when this field changes (e.g from a value 0 to 1 or 1 to 0). Can this be done via the CQ or the Kapacitor ? We have several series, so want to avoid extra queries

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to use Kapacitor. In particular you'll want to use an [alert node](http://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.1/nodes/alert_node/) and your TICKscript will look something like the following:

```
 stream
  .from()
  .measurement('mymeasurement')
  .groupBy('mytag')
 |alert()
  .stateChangesOnly()
  .info(lambda: bool("myfield"))
  .post("http://example.com/api/alert")
  .email('oncall@example.com')
```

This relies on the [stateChangesOnly](http://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.1/nodes/alert_node/#statechangesonly) which will kick off an alert when the `info` condition is met and when it returns to an `OK` state.